# Cannot fetch sorted data from mysql database by perl

Tags: mysql, perl, cgi, dbi

I am trying to create a cgi based on perl to display my album and now I am working on the sorting function on photos. I stored the information of each photo in mysql. To display all photos, I have to fetch the information first.

Here is the problem: I am expecting the fetched data from mysql is sorted by the file size of each photos, however the result from the fetchrow_array() is the data sorting according to the time being inserted into mysql.

In mysql shell, I tested

```
SELECT * FROM album ORDER BY filesize;
```

which gives the expected result sorted by the file size. Here is part of my source code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use CGI;

my $sort = 'filesize';

# Connect the database
my $dbh = do 'db.pl';

# Prepare to print out the pictures
my $query;
$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM album ORDER BY ?") or die $DBI::errstr;
$query->execute($sort) or die $DBI::errstr;

# Print out all pictures
while( my @data = $query->fetchrow_array() ){
    # Process fetched data
    (my $id, my $user, my $filepath, my $filename, my $filesize, my $uploadtime, my $description, my $tfilepath, my $sessioninfo) = @data;
    print '<fieldset>';

    # Display thumbnail
    print '<a href="', $filepath, '"><img src="', $tfilepath, '" title="', $description, '"></a>';

    # Display filename
    print '</br>';

    print $filename;
    print '</fieldset>';    
}

# Finish printing out all fetched pictures
$query->finish;
```

Am I using the wrong command? Or I am using a wrong approach to do the sorting function?
Thanks for helping!

Comment: IFAIK placeholders can be used only for values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ORDER BY` takes a field name, not an expression.

```
my $query = "SELECT * FROM album ORDER BY ".$dbh->quote_identifier($sort);
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute();
```

---

By the way, you have have bugs on the output side too. What if `$description` contains "`"`", "`&`" or "`<`"? You need some escaping.

```
sub text_to_html {
   my ($s) = @_;
   $s =~ s/&/&amp;/g;
   $s =~ s/</&lt;/g;
   $s =~ s/>/&gt;/g;
   $s =~ s/"/&quot;/g;
   $s =~ s/'/&apos;/g;
   return $s;
}
```

---

By the way,

```
(my $id, my $user, my $filepath, my $filename,
 my $filesize, my $uploadtime, my $description,
 my $tfilepath, my $sessioninfo) = @data;
```

can be written as

```
my ($id, $user, $filepath, $filename,
    $filesize, $uploadtime, $description,
    $tfilepath, $sessioninfo) = @data;
```

Comment: It works, thank you!
By the way, for escaping, why don't use CGI->escapeHTML($description)?